# Drag and Drop for Semantic-UI-React component with Packery (masonary) layout

Tags: jquery-ui, reactjs, drag-and-drop, packery

I am working on a card-based UI with brick layout. I am using semantic-ui-react for the card components and react-packery-component for the masonary layout.

My react component is this.

```
import React from 'react';
import DisplayHomePageCardStructure from   
 './DisplayHomePageCardStructure.jsx';
import {Grid} from 'semantic-ui-react';
const Packery = require('react-packery-component')(React);

let packeryOptions = {
 // transitionDuration: 0,
    gutter: 20
};

class DisplayHomePageCard extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
}

render() {
    /* Getting the values from Mongo db*/
    let Data = this.props.display.map(function(item) {
        return (
            <Grid.Column>
              <DisplayHomePageCardStructure id={item.id} displayImage= 
                {item.displayImage}
              heading={item.heading} question={item.question} postedBy=
                {item.postedBy}
              addedOn={item.addedOn} category={item.category} upVotes=
                 {item.upVotes}
              downVotes={item.downVotes} answerCounts={item.answerCounts}  '               
                  views={item.views}
              profileImage={item.profileImage}
            />
          </Grid.Column>

        );
    });
    return (
      <Packery
        elementType={'div'} options={packeryOptions} className = 'packery'>
          {Data}
        </Packery>
    );
  }
}
DisplayHomePageCard .propTypes = {
   display: React.PropTypes.func
 };
module.exports = DisplayHomePageCard;
```

As explained in https://github.com/eiriklv/react-packery-component, I'm getting the masonary layout as expected, similar to http://www.hearsay.me/.

I now want to implement drag-and-drop of my cards, somrthing functionally similiar to http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html#jquery-ui-draggable

I need advice on how to achieve this. Can it be done via React only (without JQuery)? If I need to use JQuery, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it via react only relatively simply using [`react-dnd`](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd) library.